# Alteryx download & process multi-tabbed excel

Tags: excel, download, designer, tabbed, alteryx

I am using an Alteryx workflow to download a .xlsx with multiple tabs from an FTP. The file is downloaded to temp folder as that's the option I choose. I want to further process this file by accessing various tabs. I am aware of how to process excel with multiple tabs (reading the sheet names and selecting one as template).

However, in this case, I can't select a single tab as template since the file downloaded from FTP is only created at run time. I can provide a relative path for file `%temp%test.xlsx` but can't access individual tabs to select one.
I need to schedule this workflow in Alteryx gallery so I don't want to use an absolute download path on local system that may fail when running in gallery.

Can someone throw light on how to get around this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an example of that file to develop the workflow and then change the path to %temp%test.xlsx||| with '' being one of the sheets you use.

I haven't got the exact example to test, but that should work. You may need a Block until Done before the Dynamic Input though.